# Modifying a Word Doc using OpenXML doesn't work in my Dev environment

Tags: c#, openxml

On a project I am working on, we have one very special report that absolutely has to come out as a Word document.  Yesterday, I was able to use OpenXML to get it to work on my local machine.  Everything was fine, until I committed it up to the Dev environment.

On the server, we have a content directory off of the project root (`MyProject/Content/`) which has a template file `template.dotx`.  Here's what we do with it:

**Controller:**

```
    [HasAccess]
    public FileContentResult SpecialReport([FromUri] string arg)
    {
        // Prep Report...
        string templatePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Template.dotx"));
        var report = new SpecialReport(templatePath);

        // Fill out Report...
        var models = SomeRepository.GetSomeDataPoints(arg);
        report.RunReport(models);
        byte[] reportBytes = report.Export();

        // Prep Response...
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=SpecialReport.doc");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(reportBytes, 0, reportBytes.Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return new FileContentResult(reportBytes, "application/msword");
    }
```

**Special Report Class:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

namespace MyWebProject.Web
{
    public class SpecialReport
    {
        #region Variables / Properties

        private readonly string _templatePath = string.Empty;
        public MemoryStream ReportStream;

        #endregion Variables / Properties

        #region Constructor

        public SpecialReport(string templatePath)
        {
             _templatePath = templatePath;
        }

        #endregion Constructor

        #region Methods

        public void RunReport(IList<someModel> models)
        {
            ReportStream = new MemoryStream();

            using(fs = File.OpenRead(_templatePath))
            {
                fs.CopyTo(ReportStream);
                ReportStream.Seek(0x00000000, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fs.Close();
            }

            using (WordprocessingDocument pkgDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ReportStream, true))
            {
                // Set basic properties of the document...
                pkgDoc.PackageProperties.Creator = "My Web App";
                pkgDoc.PackageProperties.Created = DateTime.Now;
                pkgDoc.PackageProperties.Title = "Special Report";
                pkgDoc.PackageProperties.ContentType = "application/msword";

                // Read the full document text, in prep for editing...
                string docText;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                {
                    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }

                // Replace the recipient.
                // Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb508261.aspx
                Regex recipientRegex = new Regex("«Recipient»");
                docText = recipientRegex.Replace(docText, models[0].EmployeeDisplayName);

                // Write other things to the document by replacing
                // special text with what needs to be replaced.

                // Write the modified document to the stream.
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    sw.Write(docText);
                    sw.Close();
                }

                // Close the unmanaged resource!
                pkgDoc.Close();
            }
        }

        public byte[] Export()
        {
            return ReportStream.ToArray();
        }

         #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

Our controller method spins off a new instance of the `SpecialReport` class, pointing to the template.  Afterwards, we get a bunch of models that are used to generate the report, then copy the template to a new `MemoryStream`.  We look in the document text for special keywords (they usually start with those weird double chevrons), and replace them as necessary.  We then write the document text back to the (cloned!) memory stream.  Afterwards, we build the HTTP response, and pass that back to the client.

What should happen, is the user does something on their front-end, that causes the document to be generated.  The resulting document has whatever data should be used.  This is occurring when the code is ran locally.

What is *actually* occurring, is that in our Dev environment, no replacement is being generated.  The «Recipient» keyword isn't being replaced with the property from the first model (the repository method always returns at least one model.)

**Question:** Why is it, given the above code, that when I run my Special Report locally, that a word document is generated with all special keywords replaced, but when I run *the exact same code* in my Development environment, that no special keywords are replaced?

Comment: Are you using the same template file in both scenarios? The XML you're running the Regex on might not be exactly what you'd expect. The spell checker for example can insert extra elements into the XML or sometimes words are split across runs. That would be enough to break your code.

Comment: The template file gets copied as part of our commit process.  I went and verified the file against my local working copy; it checks out.  I don't think that's the problem (it would have been nice if it were though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason PDFs weren't generating was because I needed to commit my Controller changes; it turns out I *wasn't actually* using the same code between my local and dev environments.

Lesson for everyone: That "Excluded Changes" list in Visual Studio?  Pay careful attention to it, make sure stuff isn't in it that needs to be pushed up.

I'm going to go repeatedly bang my head on a nearby cube, before watching *Tomb Raider* (2001) in penance, now.  I feel *really* dumb.

Comment: When you're done suffering your penance you can remember to mark this as the answer :D

Comment: As I'm answering my own question, I can't do so until two days after the original post.  But, I'll try not to forget.  Otherwise, I have a feeling this thread will wind up on The Daily WTF or something.